# word frequency from web xml, and use to filter deviantart api

Tags: python, xml, api, frequency, cpu-word

I am working on this code to sort out frequent words with some exceptions.
Then, I would like to use the most frequent word as a keyword to search and scrape image from deviantart api.

I am stuck at the point of making a list of word frequency excluding filterWords, but the order of result get messed up. Also, Can I use one of the words to search and grab an image from deviantart API?

Best,

```
    from collections import Counter
import re
import requests # for more pleasant http, use http://bit.ly/python-requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def main(n=100):

    # Download the content
    contents = requests.get('http://www.nyartbeat.com/list/event_type_print_painting.en.xml')
    root=ET.fromstring(contents.content)
    descs=[element.text for element in root.findall('.//Description')]

    # Clean the content a little

    filterWords = set(['artist', 'artists'])

    contents=",".join(map(str, descs))
    contents = re.sub('\s+', ' ', contents)  # condense all whitespace
    contents = re.sub('[^A-Za-z ]+', '', contents)  # remove non-alpha chars

    words=[w.lower() for w in contents.split() if len(w) >=6 ]


 #   fliteredWords=set(fliteredWords)-filterWords 


    # Start counting
    word_count = Counter(words)

    # The Top-N words
    print("The Top {0} words".format(n))
    for word, count in word_count.most_common(n):
        print("{0}: {1}".format(word, count))

#    with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
#        for word, count in word_count.most_common(n):
#            print("The Top {0} words".format(n))
#            print("{0}: {1}".format(word, count), file=text_file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Any suggestion please? I don't know why not all 'desc' is being parsed, it seems to chose any 'description' randomly under ./Event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse multiple XMLs (rss) from different websites for a single processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396719/how-to-parse-multiple-xmls-rss-from-different-websites-for-a-single-processing)